# How to find all possible regex matches

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to get all possible match using regex in java :

Java Tester Program :

```
 public class NewClass {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String targetFileStr = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(new File("src/SampleHTML.html")), "UTF-8");
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<body>(.|[\\r\\n])*?<link").matcher(targetFileStr);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample HTML File like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
        <script src="1"></script>
        <link href="1" />
        <link href="2" />
        <link href="3" />
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Non-Greedy Regex Current Output : Current Output of program is give below in case of non-greedy regex - `"<body>(.|[\\r\\n])*<link"`

```
<body>
        <script src="1"></script>
       <link
```

Greedy Regex Current Output : Current Output of program is give below in case of greedy regex - `"<body>(.|[\\r\\n])*?<link"`

```
<body>
            <script src="1"></script>
            <link href="1" />
            <link href="2" />
            <link
```

Expected Output : But i need to get all possible match from body to link

```
  1:   <body>
            <script src="1"></script>
           <link

  2:   <body>
            <script src="1"></script>
            <link href="1" />
            <link

  3:   <body>
            <script src="1"></script>
            <link href="1" />
            <link href="2" />
            <link
```

Why this Question : I am creating tool that will find and highlight all external style sheet in body .

Comment: I highly recommend you to use  HTML parser instead of using regexes.

Comment: Most regex engines don't work that way. What about searching for `<link` within the result string to construct the result set you want?

Comment: Do not use regex to parse HTML. Please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Is there a java HTML Parser that also gives Line and column number of match ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct approach would be using HTML parser instead of regex. This answer is to show regex mechanism that could help with similar cases that would not involve HTML or any data that already have its parser.

---

You could use look-behind mechanism to find every `<link` element that has `<body>.*` before it and place that "prefix" in some group. Unfortunately in Java look-behind content must have its max length. So you can try something like

```
String targetFileStr = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(new File(
        "input.txt")), "UTF-8");
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=(<body>.{0,1000}))<link",
        Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(targetFileStr);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + matcher.group());
    System.out.println("---------");
}
```

Output:

```
<body>
        <script src="1"></script>
        <link
---------
<body>
        <script src="1"></script>
        <link href="1" />
        <link
---------
<body>
        <script src="1"></script>
        <link href="1" />
        <link href="2" />
        <link
---------
```

Comment: @downvoter would you be so kind and tell which part of my answer is incorrect?

Comment: +1 for the "limited variable length" lookbehind.

Comment: Thanks, May you explain (?<=(<body>.{0,1000})) this

Comment: @user2998596 `(?<=...)` is [positive look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind). Combined with `(?<=..)<link` it checks if before matched `<link` there is string that matched part described in `..`. Since I surrounded this `..` part with parenthesis it is placed inside group 1 so after `matcher.find` you are able to use it with `matcher.group(1)`.

Comment: @user2998596 but seriously, combining regex with HTML is very bad idea. You really should try to solve it with some HTML or XML parser.